Cuda C++ Accessing struct from device global memory in kernel causes illegal memory access
I was working on a larger program using Nvidia Cuda toolkit but kept receiving illegal memory access errors. I ended up localizing the problem to my accessing of a struct, however, as far as I understood, the struct and all elements of the structs were allocated on the device so there should have been no illegal memory access.
This example program works fine, outputs the correct value and exits with no error:

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>


struct test_struct {
    int* arr;

    void allocate(int size);

    void deallocate();
};

void test_struct::allocate(int size) {
    cudaMalloc((void**)&arr, size);
}

void test_struct::deallocate() {
    cudaFree(arr);
}

__device__ struct test_struct* d_struct;

__global__ void print_arr(test_struct* test) {
    printf("%d\t", test->arr[0]);
}

int main()
{
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_struct, sizeof(test_struct));

    test_struct* h_test;
    h_test = (test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
    h_test->allocate(64 * sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(d_struct, h_test, sizeof(test_struct), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    print_arr << <1, 1 >> > (d_struct);
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    h_test->deallocate();
    free(h_test);
    cudaFree(d_struct);


    return 0;
}




However, changing the print_arr method to:
__global__ void print_arr() {
    printf("%d\t", d_struct->arr[0]);
}

and updating the main method accordingly print_arr << <1, 1 >> > ();
causes an illegal memory access. The rest of the code is exactly the same, but instead of accessing the struct through global memory, we pass it directly into the method. So my question is why does the first code run fine, but changing it to use global memory causes it to crash? As far as I understand it, the pointer to the arr array is the same in both cases.

I don't understand why it doesn't immediately fail with a segfault, but your d_struct is a global device-side variable. You cannot access that from the host directly. The compiler should print a warning such as "warning #20091-D: a __device__ variable "d_struct" cannot be directly read in a host function" and complain about your cudaMemcpy at the very least

Not sure whether because ofd_struct  is a global device pointer, and this global device pointers directly in the kernel. so that it causes an illegal memory access.

You could fix this by cudaMemcpying the pointer address itself from host to device memory. However, that's not typically how things are done. Rule of thumb: Except maybe for scalar return values from kernels, don't use global device memory for scalar structs or values, only arrays of decent size. You get better performance passing the struct by-value to each kernel call so that it can be accessed via the constant cache. For scalar kernel outputs,  consider managed memory or pinned host memory instead.

Maybe take a look at thrust::device_vector. Thrust comes with the CUDA Toolkit. See this example for usage with CUDA APIs/a kernel.

If you really need the object to be global, there is an example for that as well, although it is a host object in this case, i.e. you still need to pass the pointer to each kernel at launch.

When creating a global variable like this:
__device__ struct test_struct* d_struct;

in CUDA we should not attempt to use cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy directly with that symbol (d_struct).  There are a few reasons for this, one of which is that both cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy expect host storage for the pointers they access, and the __device__ decorator indicates device storage.
To provide an allocation for that device pointer, we need a 2-step process:
struct test_struct *d_struct_htemp;  // a pointer stored in host memory
cudaMalloc(&d_struct_htemp, sizeof(test_struct));  // step 1, create device allocation
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_struct, &d_struct_htemp, sizeof(test_struct *)); // step 2

Step 2 uses a different API (cudaMemcpyToSymbol) which is used to access such device variables via their device symbol.  We don't use the address-of operator for the device symbol (by convention), even though we use it for the host variable. This operation as written copies the allocated pointer value from host to device, and puts it in the d_struct pointer for further use.
Finally, for a global symbol such as d_struct we do not and should not pass it explicitly as a kernel argument:
print_arr << <1, 1 >> > (d_struct);

instead, just use it directly in kernel code, as you would a global variable/symbol.
Your code actually has pointers embedded in the struct, so an additional layer of allocations is needed, more-or-less what you have mapped out already.  Here is an example based on the code you have shown:
# cat t289.cu
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>


struct test_struct {
    int* arr;

    void allocate(int size);

    void deallocate();
};

void test_struct::allocate(int size) {
    cudaMalloc((void**)&arr, size);
    int val = 1234;
    cudaMemcpy(arr, &val, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

}

void test_struct::deallocate() {
    cudaFree(arr);
}

__device__ struct test_struct* d_struct;

__global__ void print_arr() {
    printf("%d\t\n", d_struct->arr[0]);
}

int main()
{
    test_struct *d_struct_htemp;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_struct_htemp, sizeof(test_struct));

    test_struct* h_test;
    h_test = (test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(test_struct));
    h_test->allocate(64 * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_struct_htemp, h_test, sizeof(test_struct), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_struct, &d_struct_htemp, sizeof(test_struct *));

    print_arr << <1, 1 >> > ();
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaDeviceSynchronize()) << std::endl;

    h_test->deallocate();
    free(h_test);
    cudaFree(d_struct_htemp);


    return 0;
}

# nvcc -o t289 t289.cu
# compute-sanitizer ./t289
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
1234
no error
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
#


Can you explain why cudaMalloc((void**)&d_struct, sizeof(test_struct)); doesn't immediately segfault when the host tries to access device memory?

I'm not able to explain it.  If you were to do cudaMalloc on a device allocation created with cudaMalloc (e.g. cudaMalloc((void **)d_struct_htemp,... in the example above), then you would get a segfault.  However the device symbol is handled differently.  Beyond that I can't explain it.
